# Providing path to cython shared object

Tags: cython

I am using Cython to create a module so called xyz.so which is generated locally by:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I have Spyder installed and i want to get this module imported in my spyder console just like numpy or any other standard modules.

How can i do it?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the spyder console is running out of the directory containing the cython module, you should be able to import it directly.
You can find out what directory the spyder console is running in by calling the function `os.getcwd`.